# Can't deploy Azure Open AI models due "No quota is available for this deployment. You can request for more quota."

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-openai

I wanted to test the gpt-35-turbo-16k model, so I attempted to deploy it. However, I received a message stating that there was no quota available. I initially assumed that it might be due to an existing deployment of the gpt-35-turbo model, so I deleted it. Unfortunately, I encountered the same issue even after removing the previous deployment. Furthermore, I tried redeploying the gpt-35-turbo model but was unable to do so due to the same problem.
[image]

This is my actual quota:
[image]

And those are the models that I have deployed:
[image]

Edit:

I have created two new instances after encountering the issue. The first one was just to see if the error disappears with a fresh instance, and the second one was to try a different region, but unfortunately, neither of them worked. I also purged instances in case there was another one that I didn't remember, but that wasn't the case. I am still facing the same issue. Another weird thing that occurred today was that the gpt-35-turbo-16k model disappeared from the list of deployable models.

Comment: I encountered this error as well- ironically it was in trying to deploy my first model. I managed to find a workaround by going to the Open AI resource itself rather than through oai.azure.com to get my first model deployed with no issues but now it's not prompting me there either- just telling me to go to that link. I'm assuming it's a bug but I'd really like them to fix it

Comment: @tfr950 I posted a workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened a support ticket with Microsoft and they gave me a workaround.

> In the meanwhile, as a mitigation, would you please provide
> read(microsoft.cognitiveservices/locations/usages/read) permission in
> a subscription level.  Usages API request on Open AI Studio pulls
> current usage of OpenAI from the subscription level.

Seems like the problem is related to permissions, if you deploy the model with an account with subscription level permissions you will be able to deploy the models.
In my case my user has resource group level permissions so I think is unable to "read" if there is enough quota available to do the deploy.

I think this behavior is no correct but unfortunately seems like at least this Microsoft representant isn't agree with me.

> I had a chance to further discuss this issue with the product team. I
> would like to clarify that the entire quota stack is subscription
> level based for Open AI. So being an owner/ contributor for the
> resource/ resource group wouldn't make a difference in this case. You
> need to have the permission in subscription level to make quota
> changes. Either contributor or a Reader works for subscription level
> role.   Product team are working on showing a better error message
> rather than "No quota..." and also better documentation.

I hope Microsoft realize this mistake and we will be able again to deploy models without the need of subscription level permissions.

Edit 07/03/2024:
Now Microsoft show some extra information about quota management in its documentation (someone asked so added to my answer).

[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/how-to/quota?tabs=rest#prerequisites